# How can I parse an xpath expression in Java?

Tags: java, xpath

I need to parse an xpath expression to retrieve node name/attribute/predicate/etc. from the expression for further processing. I am not addressing into a specific xml file.

For the xpath

```
/root/nodeA[@attributeA=123]
```

I would like the parsed node name: `[root, nodeA]` and for `nodeA` I have `attributeA=123`

I need to support xpath 2.0, and as far as I know, Jaxen only supports xpath 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Some Google'ing returned:

- XPath Syntax spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-xpath-parsing/
- Article about how you might use JavaCC to parse XQuery: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javacc1.html
- Page linking to the JavaCC spec for XPath 2.0: http://www.w3.org/2007/01/applets/xpathApplet.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), which does support xpath 2.0

Comment: The abstract syntax tree produced by Saxon's XPath parser is accessible to applications, though you shouldn't regard it as a stable and well documented interface. But it's there if you want to use it.

Comment: thanks, I think regular expression might be a choice for simple use case.